# Asserting that dynamic class name is not present

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, react-testing-library

I am using React Testing Library and would like to assert that a particular dynamic class name is not present on my element.

MyEl.jsx

```
const MyEl = (someCondition = false, customClassName = '') => (
    <div className={!!someCondition ? `my-custom-class-${customClassName}` : null}>
        some content
    </div>
);
```

I know that the `toHaveClass` matcher for Jest expects a proper String, but I thought I might be able to get away with doing an expect of a partial string instead...

```
it('Should not have custom class', () => {
    render(<MyEl />);

    const mainEl = screen.getByText('some content');

    expect(mainEl).not.toHaveClass(expect.stringContaining('my-custom-class-'));
})
```

This gives me the error that it is expecting a full string.

Is there something similar to what I am trying to do that will actually work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [expect.not.stringContaining(string)](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectnotstringcontainingstring)

> `expect.not.stringContaining(string)` matches the received value if it is not a string or if it is a string that does not contain the exact expected string.

> It is the inverse of `expect.stringContaining`.

And, you can get the element's class content by `el.className` attribute.

`index.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

export const MyEl = ({ someCondition = false, customClassName = '' }) => (
  <div className={!!someCondition ? `my-custom-class-${customClassName}` : ''}>some content</div>
);
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';
import { MyEl } from '.';

describe('71648378', () => {
  it('Should not have custom class', () => {
    render(<MyEl />);

    const mainEl = screen.getByText('some content');
    expect(mainEl.className).toEqual(expect.not.stringContaining('my-custom-class-'));
  });

  it('Should  have custom class', () => {
    render(<MyEl someCondition customClassName="abc" />);

    const mainEl = screen.getByText('some content');
    expect(mainEl.className).toEqual(expect.stringContaining('my-custom-class-'));
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/71648378/index.test.tsx (9.36 s)
  71648378
    ✓ Should not have custom class (23 ms)
    ✓ Should  have custom class (2 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.176 s, estimated 12 s
```